# How to execute AfterStory/AfterScenario if story failed by timeout

Tags: jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

Currently, I have next issue. I'm running test story thru jbehave-maven plugin and passing custom story timeout to it thru properties and setting it to embedder using `useStoryTimeouts`
Timeout is passed correctly, but when story is failing by timeout it's not executing AfterStory/AfterScenario steps and not generate Jbehave report.
Does somebody know how to force Jbehave to execute AfterStory if Story is failed by timeout?
Thank you

Comment: I think you should file a new bug in JBehave Jira

Comment: Created issue in [JBehave Jira](https://jbehave.atlassian.net/browse/JBEHAVE-1385)